# check whether an element is in list or not

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a matrix or list of lists:

```
x = [[1,2,3], 
     [2,3,1], 
     [3,1,2]]
```

My goal is to check whether

1) Each column of the matrix contains, each of the whole numbers from 1 to n exactly once.

2) Each row of the matrix contains each of the whole numbers from 1 to n exactly once.

This is the problem exercise that I encountered when I was solving Udacity's intro to programming course. This is my solution to the problem. I know that this is long and inefficient. So what is the short and efficient way to do this problem??

```
def check(p):
    j = 0
    for e in p:
        i = 1 + j
    s = str(p)

    if s.find('.')!= -1:
        return False

    while i < len(p):
        if p[i] == e:
            return False
        if p[i] > len(p) or p[i] < 1:
            return False
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return True

def check_sudoku(p):
    i = 0
    z = []
    a = []
    x = 0
    for e in p:
        r = check(e)
        if r == False:
            return r

    #Below here is to transpose the list
    while x < len(p):
        z.append(1)
        x += 1
    while i < len(p):
        for e in p:
            a.append(e.pop())
        z[i] = a
        i +=  1
        a = []

    #Below here is to check the transpose
    for g in z:
        r = check(g)
        if r == False:
            return r
    return True
```

Comment: 1) Your indentation is wrong. 2) Use `#` in Python to start a comment, not `\\`.  3)There's a better way to check the list contents that doesn't require converting to string. 4)You can use zip(*list2D) to transpose a list of lists.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Hi Sure I will look into these errors. It would be great if you could write an answer with efficient solution. I am pretty new to programming and python

Comment: @user00000341 the answer in the link you shared is irrelevant.

Comment: @PM2Ring - I have edited

Comment: Hopefully, I haven't destroyed your code's logic with my editing. :) BTW, it's better to do `if not r:` than `if r == False:`; similarly `if r:` is better than `if r == True:`.

Comment: @PM2Ring - now I got it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution

I cycle over rows and columns, using *zip* to flips matrix and *chain* - to combine 2 lists.
if either row or column contain values not in *valid_set*,

```
set(row) - valid_set
```

expression will yield non-empty set - turned to *False* by *not*- and *all* cycle will end

```
from itertools import chain
def check_valid(matrix, n):
   valid_set = set(range(1, n+1))
   return all(not(set(row) - valid_set) for row in chain(matrix, zip(*matrix)))
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry, misread the question; here's correct answer - *all* exits on first *False*

```
from itertools import chain
def check_valid(matrix):
   valid_set = set(range(1, len(matrix)+1))
   return all(set(row) == valid_set for row in chain(matrix, zip(*matrix)))
```

**EDIT 2:**

Out of curiosity - I timed *sort* vs *set* approach

```
In [74]: x = [[1,2,3], 
   ....:      [2,3,1], 
   ....:      [3,1,2]]

In [79]: %timeit for row in x: sorted(row)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 us per loop

In [80]: %timeit for row in x: set(row)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 836 ns per loop
```

*set* is about 30% faster

**EDIT 3:**
I fixed [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4542142/dangerous) solution and updated mine

```
In [132]: def check_valid(matrix):
    valid_num = np.unique(np.array(matrix)).tolist() # selects unique elements
    for line in matrix:
        if sorted(line) != valid_num:
            return False
    for column in zip(*matrix):
        if sorted(column) != valid_num:
            return False
    return True
In [136]: %timeit for m in (z, d): check_valid(m)
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.8 us per loop

In [115]: def check_valid_mine(matrix):                                                  
       valid_set = set(chain(*matrix))
       return all(set(row) == valid_set for row in chain(matrix, zip(*matrix)))

In [137]: %timeit for m in (z, d): check_valid_mine(m)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.96 us per loop
```

Bottom line? KISS - keep it simple stupid

**Explaining the matrix transposition by zip()**

- operator before iterable argument in a function call expands this argument list of positional arguments, essentially

  zip(*matrix)

means

```
zip(matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], ...)
```

thus rearranging columns into rows
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) for detailed explanation of * and ** operators

Comment: That will work too. But I would rather use _all_ with _not  set(row) - valid_set_.

Comment: That's even better. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks. Though it's a little too high for OP, I admit

Comment: nice way with set and itertools :)

Comment: True, the `itertools.chain()` might be a little too advanced, but it doesn't hurt to learn that these functions exist. But I reckon the set stuff is ok. Maybe you should add a solution that doesn't use itertools...

Comment: @PM2Ring that's why I posted my version - and added explanations

Comment: What is chain and all function doing here?? I am not able to understand these two functions.

Comment: @jameadreen in short, `chain` return an iterater which makes both lists `matrix` and `zip(*matrix)` look like there is only one list. So instead of using two `for loop` to check, you just need one. In long, you need to learn about key word `yield`, `generator`, and have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain and https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: _chain_ allows to iterate over collection of iterables - matrix and rotated matrix in this case, - as over sum of those iterables.
_all_ function checks whether all elements of iterable may be evaluated to _True_; it stops on first _False_ condition.
You should read it here https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/index.html

Comment: @dragon2fly and volcano - thanks for this detailed explanation. Now I got everything cleared.

Comment: @PM2Ring and Volcano - I have posted an answer that, please correct me if Iam wrong.

Comment: @dangerous and Volcano - I have posted an even simpler answer, no need to import anything, please check it out. BTW, you shouldn't care so must about the speed when you just start with python. `57.8 us` and `8.96 us` is all within a blink of eyes. And to tell the truth, `all()` is slow :D

Comment: @dragon2fly, maybe without *all* it's faster - it is just more curt. But I'll buy it. As about the speed - you noticed microseconds, but you failed to notice that it's it's 6 times faster! My main objection was over-complication - but unless you learn to think of code in terms of efficiency early, you may acquire a lousy habit of writing cluttered and inefficient code.

Comment: Actually, _set(chain(*matrix))_ is an overkill, _set(matrix[0]))_ does the trick - ans shaves off some overhead

Comment: @volcano, sorry that you thought it curt but I think you misunderstood my point. I agree that it's 6 times slower. But even if it 50 time slower, it is still in the blink of eyes. Maintain `Readability Counts` is important although the most readable code is not always the most efficient code. But when speed and memory is become a problem, try to write the most efficient code like you is the best because `Although Practicality Beats Purity`.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your check program like this:

```
def check_valid(matrix):
    n = len(matrix[0])
    valid_num = range(1, n+1)     # make a list of valid number from 1 to n

    # sort rows and column of matrix in ascending order and compare with valid_num 
    for line in matrix:
        if sorted(line) != valid_num:
            return False
    for column in zip(*matrix):
        if sorted(column) != valid_num:
            return False

    # If all rows and column is valid, then 
    return True
```

**EDIT**: follow @vocalno KISS rule but faster and work for both numbers and characters

```
def check_valid2(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)

    for line in matrix+zip(*matrix):
        if len(set(line)) != n:
            return False

    return True

In[9]: %timeit for m in (x, y): check_valid_mine(m)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.55 µs per loop

In[10]: %timeit for m in [x,y]: check_valid2(m)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.77 µs per loop
```

**EDIT 2:** all about the speed

```
def check_valid3(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)

    for line in matrix+zip(*matrix):
        if not len(set(line)) - n:
            return False

    return True

In[19]: %timeit for m in [x,y]: check_valid3(m)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.29 µs per loop
```

Comment: Will this solution work for characters as well. for eg: [[a,b,c],[b,c,a]]

Comment: @jameadreen You will have to change `valid_num` to `valid_char=[chr(c) for c in range(ord('a'), ord('c')+1)]`

Comment: I have 2 queries.  what if  why do you choose len(matrix[0]) instead of len(matrix). the character solution you have given in the comments doesnt work for characters that are greater than 'c', how should I change my code, so that even other characters are accepted.

Comment: @dangerous `len(matrix[0]) == len(matrix) == n` so it doesn't matter what you use. I've tried with n = 5 and characters from 'a' to 'e' and it worked fine. What exactly is your problem? (Traceback, error message)?

Comment: Consider this case, z = [[8,9,10], [9,10,8], [10,8,9]]. For this case your solution doesnt fit. and more over I have to write a code that fits both the alphabets and numbers.

Comment: @dangerous in that case, your numbers are not in range 1 -> n and out of your question. `valid_num = range(8, 10+1)` will work for that case. In order to work with both number and character within a specific range, you have to define that range and make it as a parameter of function

Comment: I have posted an answer, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @dragon2fly - again you are not considering unique elements.

Comment: @dangerous `unique` element is equivalent to `len(set(line)) = n`. If there are more than n elements exist in matrix, all check_valid function we wrote will False

Comment: @volcano- now I got it, can you explain the query I have asked in comments. dragon fly- Yes I understood your solution now.

Comment: @dragon2fly , dropping a set comparison is a nice touch

Comment: @dragon2fly , you are adding lists - which creates a new list that contains all the elements of the original lists. Again, it works - but it is not a good practice.

Comment: @volcano I know that you're telling me to use `chain`. It doesn't create a new list but it also slow down the code. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @dragon2fly, you guessed wrong. I am telling to use nested loop - it does the trick too

Comment: @volcano Yeah, you're right. I thought of that but I was afraid of repeating myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a solution that perfectly matches both characters and numbers and I came with a solution using numpy library. I slightly modified dragon2fly solution. Please correct me if I am wrong.  I checked the solution for both z and d values and it gave correct results.

```
 import numpy as np

z = [[8,9,10],  # example case with numbers
     [9,10,8], 
     [10,8,9]]


d =  [['a','b','c'], # example case with characters
      ['b','c','a'],
      ['c','a','b']]

def check_valid(matrix):
    valid_num = list(np.unique(matrix)) # selects unique elements


    # sort rows and column of matrix in ascend order and compare with valid_num 
    for line in matrix:
        if sorted(line) != valid_num:
            return False
    for column in zip(*matrix):
        if sorted(column) != valid_num:
            return False

    # If all rows and column is valid, then 
    return True
```

Comment: Nice with `unique`. Now the character don't need to be in any specific range.

Comment: OK, here's my evil speak:
- This solution does not work - _list(np.unique(np.array(matrix)).tolist())_ does the trick 
- You are using high-end *numpy* where simple *set* will do
- You are sorting lists - that is a relatively heavy and unnecessary (here) operation. On tiny *z[0]*  - which is already sorted! - it took 1.5 time of *set*. On z[1] and z[2] it took additional 10%
- You could have done it in 2 nested loops - instead of 2 separate loops - *for m in (matrix, zip(*matrix)):*

Comment: @volcano type(list(np.unique(z))) is a list and  type(list(np.unique(np.array(z)).tolist()) ) is also a list. then what is the difference between the two??

Comment: @volcano - also can you explain me the concept behind zip(*matrix), how does it transposes a matrix?? and also could you also explain what is going on with chain(*matrix)?? I understand that * and ** passes arguments to the function. but in this context I am unable to get the concept.

Comment: @dangerous, see my answer for explanation